# Is there any limit of data when Using "curl_exec" in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send more than 1000 Ids in $data object. When debug there are more than 1000 records in the data object but when using "curl_exec($ch);" only 996 records are received at the endpoint of the URL. I am new with the Curl and PHP thing so trying to find some suggestions to solve it. Following is my Full code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I tried by going through the curl parameters to find some solutio but no luck

Comment: You can skip `http_build_query()` and directly post an array with [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: You need to check the PHP params in the `php.ini` file on the receiving system. There are parameters that control the size of the post array that will be accepted

Comment: ...or the equivalent setting, if the receiving system does not use PHP

Comment: If you request 1_000 and get 996 back, it's not that curl has lost them most often. What happens if you request 2_000, how many do you get back? ~1_990 ?

Comment: Isn't it an associative array with some key dupes?

Comment: How about being a bit more friendly to your api host and splitting the request into chunks, not sure how many/often your making the call but it can cause performance issues with the host.

Comment: @hakre if I send any number more than 1000 still it takes only 996 records

Comment: @RoboRobok no all are unique keys

Comment: @NigelRen Actually its a requirement from the client that's why I need to send more than 1000 records, Performance is not an issue even if it takes 4-5 hours for larger data that's fine

Comment: I was more thinking that you could split this into 2/3 requests rather than 1 huge request.  The data still gets there and can be processed.

Comment: @NigelRen Right now I have implemented it for 500 at a time but the client wants to send it in a single request. Let's see if he accepts to go with splitting the requests. Thanks!

Comment: Okay 1.) you will always have limits. When you need to ask that vaguely as you do here, it looks you're not aware of *all* the limits you have in the processing. You need to create a map of every component and find out each limit (time, memory), define your own limits (this software must ..., leave at least 50% space so you can double anytime at least once (read how UTF-8 was made)) 2.) you need better verification. If you send 1000 and get back 996 and you can't directly say which 996 of the 1000 that are, this is your second problem. Design for failure & test.

Answer (score 1):

The value of PHP's `max_input_vars` is [set by default to 1,000](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

> If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

Comment: So that summarises it, I can't send more than 1000 records. If I increase the size of max_input_vars to let's say 10000 will that work in php.ini

I can't upvote this answer as I don't have 15 reputations But I THINK its correct

Comment: @AndroidBeginner: Not necessarily: If you send one [JSON Text](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) message, you can have much more than 1000 data-points. What you have there is just the php ini setting for [variables from external sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). For your process you likely want messaging (and yes, design with chunks for the transport, everything else you can never scale properly).

Comment: @AndroidBeginner Be aware that you may hit other limits. `post_max_size`, for example, defaults to 8 megabytes; if your 1,000 post variables are on the larger side, you could hit that.